# Bootstrap: Carousel not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to have a carousel in the webpage that I'm creating. The carousel should contain 3 images, but the images are simply stacked one on top of the another. This index file is located in a folder that also contains the css, fonts, and js folders. I'm not sure if this is a trivial fix, but I can't figure it out.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 
      content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media 
      queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">
        </script>
      <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carouselControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://fgl.scene7.com/is/image/FGLSportsLtd/332266454_99_a
                ? wid=288&hei=288&op_sharpen=1&resMode=sharp2" alt="First 
                slide">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://fgl.scene7.com/is/image/FGLSportsLtd/332266454_99_a
                ? wid=288&hei=288&op_sharpen=1&resMode=sharp2" alt="Second 
                slide">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://fgl.scene7.com/is/image/FGLSportsLtd/332266454_99_a 
                ? wid=288&hei=288&op_sharpen=1&resMode=sharp2" alt="Third 
                slide">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hiddin="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="carouselControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  </div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as 
      needed -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

On JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/057z6f35/1/

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your problem, either in a code snippet or on jsfiddle. You don't need your images; just use dummy images.

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @JoshEvans What we want is the code in some code snippet like this: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @JoshEvans Yup, exactly, thanks.

Comment: @xale94 I'm editing his answer right now to add that.

Comment: I put it into jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/057z6f35/1/ note that there's other stuff in there, building the rest of the webpage at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has to do with the bootstrap version you have. I suspect you are using bootstrap 3.x. In this case the carousel inner items need to have a class of "item" not "carousel-item". The carousel-item class is for the v4 alpha version. Update your code to look like:

```
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <a href="#">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" 
            src="https://fgl.scene7.com/is/image/FGLSportsLtd/332266454_99_a
            ? wid=288&hei=288&op_sharpen=1&resMode=sharp2" alt="First 
            slide">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" 
            src="https://fgl.scene7.com/is/image/FGLSportsLtd/332266454_99_a
            ? wid=288&hei=288&op_sharpen=1&resMode=sharp2" alt="Second 
            slide">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" 
            src="https://fgl.scene7.com/is/image/FGLSportsLtd/332266454_99_a 
            ? wid=288&hei=288&op_sharpen=1&resMode=sharp2" alt="Third 
            slide">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @JoshEvans If the answer does what you need it to, please accept it so that others who come across your question can see what fixed the issue.